# Find files with special character in file-name in unix

Tags: shell, unix, sh, ksh

Q:I am working with script on unix platform and I have to find out all the files in a directory which came around 8 hours early from now.

i am using below command to retrieve the files as per above condition:

```
find . name "*.dat" -mmin -480
```

But there are few files which are having special character(double question mark) `??`" in the file-name itself and using above command ,file with `??` in its name ,got splits into two part  in two lines.

for eg:

```
file name : aabb??cc.dat
```

after above command run,it results like this :

```
$./aabb

$cc.dat
```

($ here is unix command prompt)
Can someone suggest the correction in the above command or the right approach to handle this exception.

Comment: find isn't going to split up a filename. show the rest of your script.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "special character". There are only characters. Lots of those buggers.

Comment: @MarcB my purpose here is not to split the file .I want to search the file in a directory with complete file name but this file (aabb??cc.dat) is splitting into two names,which is an issue for me.

Comment: then show HOW the filename is being split. `find` doesn't split filenames, so it must be something YOU'RE doing.

Comment: @avisingh05 It is perfectly legal for a file name to contain one or more newline characters.  What do you want to have happen in that case?  The correct (but advanced way) way to handle difficult filenames is with NUL-separated lists: see find's `-print0` option.  To use a NUL-separated list productively, though, we need to see what you want to do with the file names.

Comment: @MarcB Yeah...I agree ,find doesn't split but i am running above command in k-Shell and it breaking the name in new line

Comment: The output of the find command would be without the `$` unix prompt. What do you want to do with the files that find finds? When you just want to see them, try the find option -ls.

Comment: Where are you seeing the question marks?  In a file, or at the terminal?  Is your terminal running with UTF-8 as its code set?  If so, there are file names created using other code sets, such as ISO 8859-15, that won't display properly.  I think you should run the output of `find` through a hex dump program (or `od -c`, or something similar) and see what bytes it identifies where the question marks appear.  That will likely tell you a lot about the problem.  Bytes in the range 0x80..0xC1, or 0xF5..0xFF, are particularly problematic.  Any bytes over 0x80 can be a problem if UTF-8 is a factor.

Comment: As it is, this doesn't include enough information to be actionable -- it doesn't show *how* you're trying to use your shell to interpret the results from `find`, and that code is where the bug is.

Answer (score 0):

This command will show you `find` is considering these files just like the others :

```
find . -name "*.dat" -mmin -480 -exec \
  ksh -c 'c=1
          for file do
              printf "file #%d is \"%s\"\n" $c "$file"
              c=$((c+1))
          done ' sh {} +
```

If `find` is showing some file names split in two lines, that's just because their names have an embedded new line. That's odd but they are still valid file names.

Comment: You need a semicolon before the `do` of `for file do printf`, at minimum.  The script is unreadable because it stretches for miles.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My understanding is there is no need for such a semicolon according to the POSIX `for` loop grammar. Newlines inserted for readability.

Comment: Interesting.  Because of the absence of an `in` and a list of arguments (e.g. no `for file in "$@";`), the semicolon doesn't seem to be necessary, though it doesn't do any harm either.  I sit corrected.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler According to the standard, the semicolon is even invalid here. No mainstream posix shell is strict enough to refuse it though.